# Why is this code not returning a string?

Tags: java, if-statement

Sorry about the ugly code. (I'm new coder trying to teach myself Java.)
I was just wondering why the compiler on http://codingbat.com refuses to run this and instead returns the error:

`This method must return a result of type String`

Here is the code.......................

```
public String startOz(String str) {
    if (str.length() <= 2) {
        return str;
    }

    else if (str.charAt(0) == 'o' && str.charAt(1) != 'z') {
        return "o";
    }

    else if (str.charAt(1) == 'z' && str.charAt(0) != 'o') {
        return "z";
    }

    else if (str.substring(0 , 3).equals("oz")) {
        return "oz";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were running this on an actual IDE, like eclipse, you would get the error:

```
missing return statement
```

Now you may be thinking,

> "But Ruchir, I have 4 return statements already!"

**No.** Those return statements are all in if statements, meaning **if** the if statement isn't executed, the compiler won't know what to return. This will throw the null pointer exception.

If you are sure that one of those if statements will be executed, just put an empty return statement:

```
return;
```

By making a method without void, you are saying it **will** return something.

Just add a return statement outside of the if statement.

Comment: Thanks Ruchir. Beautifully organized and easy to understand answer <3

Comment: @EugeneL. Thanks, I am happy to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to think about what will be returned if *none* of those `if` conditions turns out to be true. Such as if you pass in the string `"paxdiablo"`.

A simple:

```
return "Stuffed if I know!";
```

before the function closing brace may be all that's needed, though you'll probably want to use something a little more appropriate :-)

---

Actually, scratch that. Sit down with a pen and paper and actually write down all the inputs you expect and what the output should be for all of them.

Then think about what the output should be if the input *isn't* what you expect. Translating that to a series of `if` statements and a final `return` statement should then be quite easy.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String startOz(String str) {
if (str.length() <= 2) {
   return str;
}

else if (str.charAt(0) == 'o' && str.charAt(1) != 'z') {
   return "o";
}

else if (str.charAt(1) == 'z' && str.charAt(0) != 'o') {
return "z";
}

else if (str.substring(0 , 3).equals("oz")) {
  return "oz";
}

return "Your last default String to return.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add the last else statement at the end, which will execute when none of your if condition runs, like below -

```
else if (str.substring(0 , 3).equals("oz")) {
  return "oz";
}
else{
    return " last string to return" ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if none of your 'if' conditions are met you still need to return a String or simply add the following to the bottom of your method.

```
return null;
```